# d3-venn / venn.js Venn Circles are coming out enclosed within each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js, venn.js

[Issue Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoWRe.png)

Currently I am having an issue where when I generate my venn diagram layout, I get a venn diagram without intersections and instead circles that become enclosed. I want to generate my venn diagram with clear intersections such as the above example labeled C but instead some of the venn diagram intersections are getting enclosed in the root circle.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Found the issue. venn.js presets the size of the venn diagrams so certain venn diagrams with 1 node will end up becoming enclosed. I had to manually set the size of my sets within venn.js and that helped fixed the solution.